# Variable from HTML to PHP error

Tags: php, html

I have a html from that saves the user input in a separate page called "welcome.php"

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And if I just echo the input, it works;

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
```

So far so good, but when I try to declare the input to a new variable or to a if-statement id does not work as usual. For example;

```
  Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; <br>


    $new = $_POST["name"];

    echo $new;

    ?>
```

or

```
if ($_POST["name"] === "hi");
{
etc...
}
```

How do I sort it out? How do I use a user input from a HTML-form with php variables?

Comment: _does not work as usual_ what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The `<br>` is most likely causing some issues,  - Please include your actual code instead of some pseudo code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<br>` from your PHP code.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Would never guessed that <br> would cause the problem.

Comment: <br> is html code. When you are in php block you can not directly use html syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo 'Welcome' . $_POST["name"] . '<br>';

$new = $_POST["name"];

echo $new;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to con-cat `<br>` with `$_POST["name"]`. This has syntax error as `<br>` is not terminate with semicolumn(`;`).

Try This

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]."<br>";
$new = $_POST["name"];
echo $new;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $new  = $_POST['name'];
echo "Welcome ".$new."<br/>";
echo "<p>".$new."</p>";
  ?>
```

Try Using this. I hope this will be helful.

Thanks